# Why get "Expected #0, Actual #1" when using StringDictionary in RhinoMocks 3.6

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Today I changed to use `StringDictionary` instead of `Dictionary<string,string>` in my code, but old unit test failed. So I write a small unit test to test this.

Here is my small test:

```
using Rhino.Mocks;
using NUnit.Framework;
//using CustomDictionary = System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary;
using CustomDictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface ITest
    {
        void DoSth(CustomDictionary dic);
    }
    public class OneTest : ITest
    {
        public void DoSth(CustomDictionary dic) {/*do nothing*/}
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var mockRepository = new MockRepository();
            var test = mockRepository.StrictMock<ITest>();

            using (mockRepository.Record())
            {
                Expect.Call(() => test.DoSth(new CustomDictionary { { "Test", "Test1" } }));
            }
            test.DoSth(new CustomDictionary { { "Test", "Test1" } });

            mockRepository.VerifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

If I use `Dictionary<string,string>`, the test will pass, but when I use `StringDictionary`, the test failed.

What's the problem here?

Comment: curious, why use StringDictionary rather than Dictionary?

Comment: The reason why I use StringDictionary is just because the legacy code in the system uses this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem goes from `StringDictionary` instances comparison. There is no overridden `Equals` method, thus instances compared not by content, but by references. If you will use same instance, test will pass:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var mockRepository = new MockRepository();
        var test = mockRepository.StrictMock<ITest>();
        var dictionary = new CustomDictionary { { "Test", "Test1" } };

        using (mockRepository.Record())            
            Expect.Call(() => test.DoSth(dictionary));

        test.DoSth(dictionary);
        mockRepository.VerifyAll();
    }
```

You can override `Equals` on your `CustomDictionary` class to make your original test pass:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    CustomDictionary other = obj as CustomDictionary;
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    if (Count != other.Count)
        return false;

    foreach (string key in Keys)
    {
        if (!other.ContainsKey(key))
            return false;

        if (this[key] != other[key])
            return false;
    }

    foreach (string key in other.Keys)
    {
        if (!ContainsKey(key))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

BTW I hope this is not your real test, because here you are testing mock, instead of testing your code.

WHY YOUR CODE WORKS WITH DICTIONARY:

As I understand RhinoMocks implementation, `Rhino.Mocks.Impl.Validate` class used for arguments validation. You can take a look on it's `ArgsEqual` method implementation:

```
public static bool ArgsEqual(object[] expectedArgs, object[] actualArgs)
{
    return RecursiveCollectionEqual(expectedArgs, actualArgs);
}
```

I leave to you details of `RecursiveCollectionEqual`, but interesting part there is arguments comparison:

```
if (current == null)
{
    if (actual != null)
        return false;
}
else if (!SafeEquals(current, actual))
{
    if (current is ICollection)
    {
        if (!RecursiveCollectionEqual((ICollection)current, (ICollection)actual))
            return false;

        continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, if argument is `ICollection` then Rhino goes deeper to compare expected and actual collections. `Dictionary` implements `ICollection`, but `StringDictionary` does not. Thus arguments of `StringDictionary` types compared only by reference.

UPDATE: Didn't notice, that you have an alias. Just inherit from type instead, and you will be able to override `Equals`:

```
public class CustomDictionary : StringDictionary
```

Comment: Useful information, but what i'm stll confusing is there's also no overridden Equals method in Dictionary, why it can pass the test.

Comment: Note that CustomDictionary is just an alias for System class (StringDictionary or Dictionary<T, T>), so the user can't change its Equals() implementation.

Comment: @Eric see my updated answer. Amittai, thanks, updated this part also.

Comment: Great! I have updated my UT to compare the elements manually to avoid of "ArgsEqual". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps, but the main difference between the two is that StringDictionairy does automatically lower-case all your keys (Test becomes test). Maybe thats why the test fails?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Rhino Mocks compares **by reference** when checking whether the parameters passed in the Expect.Call() match the parameters actually passed.
The problem in your code is that you create 2 **different object** of custom dictionary, one for the expectation and one for the actual call, therefore they're not matched:

```
        using (mockRepository.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(() => test.DoSth(new CustomDictionary { { "Test", "Test1" } }));
        }
        test.DoSth(new CustomDictionary { { "Test", "Test1" } });
```

It can easily fixed as follows (also removes duplication):

```
        var myDictionary = new CustomDictionary { { "Test", "Test1" } }));
        using (mockRepository.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(() => test.DoSth(myDictionary);
        }
        test.DoSth(myDictionary );
```

Comment: How this answer differs from mine?

Comment: The solution is different, I think, I don't suggest to override Equals() in any way, and it's much less code.

Comment: See first paragraph in my answer, I don't see anything different in this solution